# hide overflowed content with jQuery or css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to edit this so that when the user clicks the content the div shifts over to the right. Using this with Marginleft 40% and width 60% works. However it squishes the pictures I want to be seen. So I just push the margin 40% and let the rest overflow off the page (mobile). My problem is, when I try to overflow hidden the body, and HTML. It doesn't catch anything and the page is still scrollable to the right. I also tried scrollLock/scrollLeft type options that didn't work either. Any know of a solution?

here is the Jfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/56hxy/112/

```
$(function() { 
    var contentToggle = 0; 

    $('#content').on('click', function() { 

        if (contentToggle == 0) { 
            $('#content').animate({
                marginLeft: '40%',
            })  

            contentToggle = 1; 
        }
        else if (contentToggle == 1) {
            $('#content').animate({
                marginLeft: 0,
            }) 
            contentToggle = 0; 
        }

    }) 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `overflow: hidden` on `body` element, or in a container, like this:

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/56hxy/113/

Comment: It made hide my content on the y but 1. i could still scroll the Y and 2. the content was still visible outside the container.

Comment: But this fiddle work not? So you should have to create a new fiddle showing your problem.